# All Functions Throwing Errors

Tags: powershell

My powershell scripts were all throwing errors this morning, stating that all of the functions were invalid, functions like `New-Object`, `Get-Content`, etc.  I tried

- Restarting the server (no effect).
- Checking the powershell version (5.0).
- Checking the execution policy (unrestricted).
- Verifying permissions of the account that was calling the scripts (fine) and it's the account I was using to login.
- Manually doing some tasks, like opening a file and copying content and it worked.  As direct as possible - I could do everything that the script was doing, but I was doing it through the interface, like manually clicking on a file, hitting `CTRL C` and then pasting it in another folder (and other tasks like that where the script was designed to do it).

I'd like to say, "I fixed it by" but I can't.  After waiting a few minutes to think about what it could possibly be, I tried running a script again, and it worked.

Has anyone run into something like this, and what could be the issue here where all powershell functions didn't work?

**UPDATE**

The errors all looked identical:

`The term 'New-Object' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet ...`
`The term 'Get-Content' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet ...`

Based on the responses, this confirms that this is very unusual behavior and may be more of a Windows issue.

Comment: What does the error state _exactly_? Something like _The term 'get-bagel' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,_? Does `Get-Module` work and return something? Also you are showing examples of cmdlets not functions.

Comment: You said _opening a file and copying content_ worked but then _All powershell functions didn't work._..... How did you copy the file?

Comment: show the error message(s)

Comment: So you can copy a file outside of PowerShell all together? That context was missing in your question therefore was misleading. So get-module also does not work?

Comment: Consider trying to reinstall WMF 5.0 maybe?

Comment: If it happens again, run `ls function:` and post the results (or part of the results if they are long)

Answer (score 2):

Your `PSModulePath` system environment variable was probably missing `C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules` which is the location of all built-in modules in PowerShell. This may happen when a badly written module *replaces* the value of `PSModulePath` instead of *appending* a new path.

To verify, run:

```
[environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("PSModulePath","Machine")
```

Is `C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\` missing? If so, add it.

The easiest way to do it without PowerShell is using the GUI as described here: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

If it was temporary, then the variable at the process level may have been modified. The process-level variable can be read using:

```
[environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("PSModulePath","Process")
```

Comment: The error hasn't happened again, so I wish I could verify what it was, but I am upvoting this answer because this might be the issue and if it happens again, I am curious if running this will confirm it.  I've been working with PS for a while and have never seen this occur.  Thanks for this answer.